# Excel: Rollover Effect for calendar based on event date

Tags: excel, vba, calendar, rollover

I have my custom made calendar where I emphasize special events using formulas in conditional formating:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(G14;EVENTS;0)))
```

where EVENTS is a range of dates with some event occurance.

```
EVENTS             Description
08.05.2014          Anniversary
10.05.2014          Meeting
```

Now, I would like to create a mouse rollover efect within the calendar area, which would show the description  of the event  (something like a dynamic comment) when  moving the mouse over emphasized date in calendar.

I was thinking of using hyperlink and help of [How to Create a Rollover Effect in Excel: Execute a Macro When Your Mouse is over a Cell](http://optionexplicitvba.blogspot.co.at/2011/04/rollover-b8-ov1.html) , but I am not sure how to match the dates with description.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these tutorials:

- http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2012/11/roll-over-tooltips-and-web-actions-on-a-microsoft-excel-dashboard.html
- http://optionexplicitvba.com/2013/09/13/handling-excel-rollover-popups/

I am the author of the blog cited above, so please let me know if you have trouble implementing the tutorials above.